# how to attach multiple instances with multiple resources in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have 3 services named valid,test,jsc and each have 3 ec2 instances and each have 1 loadbalancer target group.Now i want to attach each 3 respective ec2 instances to their target group

```
variable "service-names" {
  type = list
  default = ["valid","jsc","test"]
  
}

locals {
  helper_map = {for idx, val in setproduct(var.service-names, range(var.instance_count)): 
                   idx => {service_name = val[0]}
               }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "ecom-tgp" {
  for_each = toset(var.service-names)
  name = "${each.value}-tgp"
  port = 80
  protocol = "TCP"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.ecom-vpc.id
  target_type = "instance"
  deregistration_delay    = 90
  health_check {
    interval            = 30
    port                = 80
    protocol            = "TCP"
    healthy_threshold   = 3
    unhealthy_threshold = 3
  }
  tags = {
    "Name" = "${each.value}-tgp"
  }
  
}

output "ecom-instance-details" {
  value = data.aws_instances.ecom-instances
}
```

Below is the sample i service instances details from terraform output

```
ecom-instance-details = {
  "test" = {
    "filter" = toset(null) /* of object */
    "id" = "ap-south-1"
    "ids" = tolist([
      "i-0fab28125d684f9d2",
      "i-0b90e3501715681df",
      "i-066bff51352660006",
    ])
    "instance_state_names" = toset([
      "running",
      "stopped",
    ])
    "instance_tags" = tomap({
      "Name" = "test-service"
    })
    "private_ips" = tolist([
      "10.0.3.11",
      "10.0.3.10",
      "10.0.3.8",
    ])
    "public_ips" = tolist([])
  }
vpc-id = "vpc-051198b7ebaa3bd53"
```

I'm trying like below.But since it is having 3 ids in a list,it is not accepting that to pass to target_id which is basically a string

```
 resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "ecom-tga" {
   for_each      = local.helper_map
     target_group_arn  = aws_lb_target_group.ecom-tgp[each.value.service_name].arn
     port              = 80
   target_id           = data.aws_instances.ecom-instances[each.value.service_name].ids
 }
```

Could you please guide me

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on main.tf line 500, in resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "ecom-tga":
│  500:      target_id           = data.aws_instances.ecom-instances[each.value.service_name].ids
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.aws_instances.ecom-instances is object with 3 attributes

Comment: since 3 id's are there unable to pass each id.Need some looping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can construct a helper local variable and use that:

```
locals {

  env_instance_map = merge([for env, value in var.ecom-instance-details:
                  {
                    for id in value.ids:
                    "${env}-${id}" => {
                      "env" = env
                      "id" = id
                    }
                  }
                ]...)
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "ecom-tga" {
   for_each          = local.env_instance_map
   target_group_arn  = aws_lb_target_group.ecom-tgp[each.value.env].arn
   port              = 80
   target_id         = each.value.id
}
```

Comment: awesome marcin.worked like charm.Just changed the var to data source

Comment: @user10912187 No problem. Glad it worked out:-)

Comment: unfortunately,not able to run entire config in a stretch because of - 517:    for_each          = local.service_instance_map
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.service_instance_map will be known only after apply
│ 
│ The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will
│ be created. To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the resources that the for_each depends on

Comment: @user10912187 Sadly I don't know what is your full setup. In your question it seems that you know entire data structure up front.